# API implementation in Excel

Tags: json, excel, import

Having some problems with and API that I'm trying to import in to Excel. I get one column imported to Excel but not the other one.

[image: How the columns look on the website].

I'm trying to import them from the Swedish statistical institute. [SCB](https://www.statistikdatabasen.scb.se/pxweb/sv/ssd/START__PR__PR0101__PR0101A/KPItotM/table/tableViewLayout1/) (link doesn't go directly to the specified columns but might be of some use)

Used the "from web" function in Excel "data" tab, used this URL; https://api.scb.se/OV0104/v1/doris/sv/ssd/START/PR/PR0101/PR0101A/KPItotM

There is also an JSON question on the website:

```
{
  "query": [
    {
      "code": "ContentsCode",
      "selection": {
          "filter": "item",
          "values": [ "000004VU" ]
      }
    },
    {
      "code": "Tid",
      "selection": {
          "filter": "item",
          "values": [ "1980M09", "1981M09", "1982M09", "1983M09", "1984M09",
                      "1985M09", "1986M09", "1987M09", "1988M09", "1989M09",
                      "1990M09", "1991M09", "1992M09", "1993M09", "1994M09",
                      "1995M09", "1996M09", "1997M09", "1998M09", "1999M09",
                      "2000M09", "2001M09", "2002M09", "2003M09", "2004M09",
                      "2005M09", "2006M09", "2007M09", "2008M09", "2009M09",
                      "2010M09", "2011M09", "2012M09", "2013M09", "2014M09",
                      "2015M09", "2016M09", "2017M09", "2018M09", "2019M09",
                      "2020M09", "2021M09", "2022M09", "2023M09", "2023M11" ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "response": {
    "format": "px"
  }
}
```

But I'm not sure how to use that one in Excel, well I tried to import the JSON file but to no avail. My understanding is that I'm not of any need of passwords etc.

[image: How it looks in excel]

Expected both columns to be imported but only got one.

[This is the guide](https://www.codementor.io/@benniejayguevarra/importing-public-web-api-to-excel-no-coding-required-14bzfy4nev)

**Uppdate** **Using the following code;**

```
    let
    url = "https://api.scb.se/OV0104/v1/doris/en/ssd/START/PR/PR0101/PR0101A/KPItotM",

    jsonReq = Text.ToBinary(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="jsonReq"]}[Content]{0}[JSON Req]),

    web = Web.Contents(url, [Content=jsonReq]),
  
    json =Json.Document(web),
  
    #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(json),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Converted to Table", each ([Name] = "data")),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Name"}),

    #"Expanded Value" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Value"),
    #"Expanded Value1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Value", "Value", {"key", "values"}, {"key", "values"}),
    
    #"Expanded key" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Expanded Value1", "key"),
    #"Expanded values" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Expanded key", "values"),
    
    #"Transform to Numbers" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Expanded values", {"values", each Number.From(_)}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Transform to Numbers",{{"key", type text}, {"values", Currency.Type}},"sv-SE")
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

**uppdate v2**
In my JSON file on the computer

```
{"queryObj":{
  "query": [
    {
      "code": "ContentsCode",
      "selection": {
        "filter": "item",
        "values": [
          "000004VU"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "code": "Tid",
      "selection": {
        "filter": "item",
        "values": [
          "1980M09",
          "1981M09",
          "1982M09",
          "1983M09",
          "1984M09",
          "1985M09",
          "1986M09",
          "1987M09",
          "1988M09",
          "1989M09",
          "1990M09",
          "1991M09",
          "1992M09",
          "1993M09",
          "1994M09",
          "1995M09",
          "1996M09",
          "1997M09",
          "1998M09",
          "1999M09",
          "2000M09",
          "2001M09",
          "2002M09",
          "2003M09",
          "2004M09",
          "2005M09",
          "2006M09",
          "2007M09",
          "2008M09",
          "2009M09",
          "2010M09",
          "2011M09",
          "2012M09",
          "2013M09",
          "2014M09",
          "2015M09",
          "2016M09",
          "2017M09",
          "2018M09",
          "2019M09",
          "2020M09",
          "2021M09",
          "2022M09",
          "2023M09"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "response": {
    "format": "json"
  }
},"tableIdForQuery":"KPItotM"}
```

And in excel:

```
    let
    url = "https://api.scb.se/OV0104/v1/doris/en/ssd/START/PR/PR0101/PR0101A/KPItotM",
  
    jsonReq = File.Contents("C:\Users\Alexa\Desktop\JSON-question.json"),

    web = Web.Contents(url, [Content=jsonReq]),
  
    json =Json.Document(web),
  
    #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(json),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Converted to Table", each ([Name] = "data")),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Name"}),

    #"Expanded Value" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Value"),
    #"Expanded Value1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Value", "Value", {"key", "values"}, {"key", "values"}),
    
    #"Expanded key" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Expanded Value1", "key"),
    #"Expanded values" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Expanded key", "values"),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded values",{{"key", type text}, {"values", Currency.Type}}, "en-US")
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Comment: It is always useful to include the code you are using when you have code that isn't working the way you want it to. In this case, the code is to be found in the `Advanced Editor` of Power Query.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code that seems to work with the request you show.

Paste this code into the `Advanced Editor` of `Power Query`.

Change the `Response` parameter in your json request from "px" to "json"

I stored the request in a table in Excel, but you can hard code it into the query if you prefer.

I suggest you read the code comments and follow the applied steps to better understand the logic.

```
let
    url = "https://api.scb.se/OV0104/v1/doris/en/ssd/START/PR/PR0101/PR0101A/KPItotM",

//In your json formatted request, in the "response" paramater, change "px" to "json"
//I stored my request in an Excel table named `JSON Req` but you can put it anyplace
  
    jsonReq = Text.ToBinary(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="jsonReq"]}[Content]{0}[JSON Req]),

//Note the web contents includes the request
    web = Web.Contents(url, [Content=jsonReq]),
  
    json =Json.Document(web),
  
//Extract and format the desired information
    #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(json),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Converted to Table", each ([Name] = "data")),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Name"}),

    #"Expanded Value" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Value"),
    #"Expanded Value1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Value", "Value", {"key", "values"}, {"key", "values"}),
    
    #"Expanded key" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Expanded Value1", "key"),
    #"Expanded values" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Expanded key", "values"),
    
    #"Transform to Numbers" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Expanded values", {"values", each Number.From(_)}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Transform to Numbers",{{"key", type text}, {"values", Currency.Type}},"sv-SE")
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

***Results from your request***
[image]

***Edit:**
Alternative code storing json in a text file instead of in a workbook cell*

```
let
    url = "https://api.scb.se/OV0104/v1/doris/en/ssd/START/PR/PR0101/PR0101A/KPItotM",
  
    jsonReq = File.Contents("C:\users\ron\desktop\test.json"),

//Note the web contents includes the request
    web = Web.Contents(url, [Content=jsonReq]),
  
    json =Json.Document(web),
  
//Extract and format the desired information
    #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(json),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Converted to Table", each ([Name] = "data")),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Name"}),

    #"Expanded Value" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Value"),
    #"Expanded Value1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Value", "Value", {"key", "values"}, {"key", "values"}),
    
    #"Expanded key" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Expanded Value1", "key"),
    #"Expanded values" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Expanded key", "values"),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded values",{{"key", type text}, {"values", Currency.Type}}, "en-US")
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Comment: Okey! Have tried it but i dont understand where I should put the code that you posted, etidted my json request as you told and imported it to excel. But should there be 2 requests in the power query?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/3zYSQcg

Comment: @Alexander Paste it **as I wrote** into the advanced editor. If you are using Excel to store the json request as I did, then make it a table with the name of the table being `jsonReq` and column header being `JSON Req`. And paste the code into the Power Query editor of that same workbook. The entire request string is stored in a **SINGLE** Cell. If you are storing the Json Request some other way, then you'll have to code differently.

Comment: Got the code to work somewhat, I do get the columns now but they don't have any text in them. [How it looks like] https://imgur.com/a/2PY3u2y    it says that data in reading in but waited for over 15+ min and nothing has happened. @Ron

Comment: @Alexander Since you have chosen to **not include** the code you are actually using, as I requested in my **first comment to you** under your **question**, I can have no idea what you might be doing wrong. Obviously, as you can see from my screenshots, the code and process I am using works. If you change your mind about providing code **AS TEXT** which can be copy/pasted, edit your question to include the code.

Comment: I forgot that comment, sorry! I've now updated my original question with the code.

Comment: @Alexander and is your jsonreq table in a single cell with a proper name and column header ?

Comment: @Alexander If the jsonreq is in a single cell and properly named, your code appears to be OK. Please do the following: `Advanced Editor`=>Remove `Text.ToBinary` (just that, not the parentheses) from the `jsonReq` step =>`Done` =>under `Applied Steps` select `jsonReq`. The contents of the Json should appear in the window. Copy/Paste all of that text into your question as an edit. (After, go back into the Advanced Editor and replace the `Text.ToBinary`). If that doesn't work, please upload your workbook to some sharing site (eg Google Drive or OneDrive) and post a link here and I'll take a look.

Comment: Well, I created one with the correct name and title and then imported my JSON file (which I then edited in excel), but the JSON  got imported in a new sheet, I tried to fix them in the same sheet but it did not work. **(side just updated with your new comment, this applies to the old one, will chek the new one out)**

Comment: Edited the code but it did not seem to help, uploaded my Excel file; https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1iq_QxWh-98UZs6VKfOccebiI9WkvlaJG?usp=sharing

Comment: @Alexander The purpose of editing the code was not to fix things. It was to troubleshoot so as to see what is in the jsonRequest you are sending. I suspect there is nothing there and all you see is `null`. That is the source of your problem. Take a look at the first cell of the table and ensure there is something there. As I have been emphasizing, the entirely of that json should be in a single cell. Be sure to re-add the `Text.ToBinary` that you deleted and fix your json.

Comment: @Alexander Since you seem to be having so much trouble storing your json request in a cell in the workbook, I have provided alternate code which uses the json stored in a text file on your desktop by changing the `jsonReq` step.

Comment: Hi again! Happy new years! So I've tried the changes you recommended (changed the jsonReq step to refer to my JSON text file). However now i get a "bad request" message. (Very new to the whole API part and to programming in general, but i appreciate the help!) [Image from excel] https://imgur.com/a/EPhpZeS

Comment: @Alexander My guess is that there is an error in your json request file and that it does not match what you show in your question.

Comment: Made a new edit, "uppdate v2" with the code that im using, can you see any faults? @Ron

Comment: @Alexander I have mentioned possible issues with your `jsonReq` data multiple times. And, in your excel workbook you uploaded, I also mentioned that you had NO DATA in the jsonReq table. It seems to me the logical response when I write *"My guess is that there is an error in your json request file"* would be to provide the data that is in that file. Your code doesn't do that so is not useful in figuring out your problem.